Python dataframe restrict column width without truncation
I have very long column lengths. I just wanted to know how i can restrict the width of each column without truncating it, so that if the column length is beyond the width it should get displayed as a new line instead of jumping to next column.
How its printing now.
======================
column1 column2
xxxxxx    yyyyyyyy.....

OR

column1 column2
xxxxxx    yyyyyyyyyyyy...(till screen width)
yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy(till screen width)
yyyyyyyyyyy ...
 
How I would like it to display
==============================

column1 column2
xxxxxx    yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy(till screen width)
          yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy(till screen width)
          yyyyyyyyyyy

Posting more clarifications based on comments already provided. display.max_colwidth only helps in preventing truncation. It doesn't help here since the long line still jumps into the next line of the first column as show in the example above (example in "How its printing now."). Here my requirement is to display long lines like in column2 where the long lines automatically breaks into multiple short lines (example in "How I would like it to display")
Already tried following options, but still the long lines in column2 spills into column1 like second example under "How its printing now."
pd.set_option("display.max_rows",None)
pd.set_option('display.width', 50)
pd.set_option("display.max_colwidth", None)
pd.set_option("display.colheader_justify","left")


This question is similar to: Print very long string completely in pandas dataframe. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Together with this post. E.g., you can do something like pd.options.display.max_colwidth = None with pd.options.display.max_columns = None. For future ref, please always include a [mre]. E.g., try that on df = pd.DataFrame([{k: k*n for k, n in zip('abcdef', range(40, 100, 10))}]*2).
